# Framework to develop a WordPress theme, with Responsive Bootstrap/FontAwesome/Google Maps

Tags: gratis, framework, wordpress

I want to develop a WordPress theme, and rather than developing from scratch I want to use a framework.

Requirements:

- Free
- Responsive Bootstrap support
- FontAwesome icons support
- Nice 'back to top'
- Google Maps support
- Drag-and-drop editor in admin/
- On design without customization is OK. I don't need a million admin settings for customizing a theme design. This means hardcode header and footer backgrounds and even logo into the theme (to make is simple to start as quick as possible).
- all the links, footer widgets, and page content should be manageable via WordPress admin and its core standard functions.